# Monotonically increasing bazaar trunk revision numbers

Tags: bazaar, launchpad

I'm still figuring out how bazaar's revision numbering works. The workflow our team uses is basically:

```
bzr branch lp:project/trunk
# code,code,code
bzr commit ...
# code,code,code
bzr commit ...
bzr merge
# resolve, resolve, resolve
bzr push lp:project/trunk
```

I'd prefer it if the trunk revision numbering was stable and increased monotonically with each push. However, as I understand it, whoever does `bzr merge; bzr push lp:project/trunk` ends up renumbering the revision history of the trunk to whatever their local branch revision numbering was. This makes things very confusing for the team, because "trunk, revision 705" may change over time.

We could use global ids, but it's a little awkward to work with a long string like `foo@example.com-20110224160420-nnob0vg2vdk0yjow`.

Is there any way to arrange our workflow so that the trunk revision numbering scheme is stable and increases monotonically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the trunk on your central server, edit 
`<yourbranch>/.bzr/branch/branch.conf` or `~/.bazaar/locations.conf` or `~/.bazaar/bazaar.conf`

add `append_revisions_only=True`

This branch's existing revision order will not change any more.

http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/beta/en/user-reference/configuration-help.html#append-revisions-only

**Edit**: For launchpad you can try the following as John Arbash Meinel said:

> At the moment, the only way to get a branch with that 
>   option is during "bzr init".
>
> bzr init --append-revisions-only
>
> So you *could*:
>
> 1) have launchpad delete the existing branch
>
> 2) bzr init --append-revisions-only lp:...
>
> 3) bzr push lp:...
>
> Not exactly optimal.
>
> The other way to do it is to use sftp and do:
>
> sftp bazaar.launchpad.net
>
> > cd ~user/project/branch/.bzr/branch
> >     get branch.conf
>
> Then outside of sftp, edit the file to add 
>   append_revisions_only = True
>
> > put branch.conf

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/bazaar/2008q3/046797.html

Comment: Our trunk lives on Launchpad. Is it possible to change this setting on Launchpad?

Comment: I added info for doing it on launchpad to my answer (because comments doesn't really format well).

Comment: The docs say "A branch with this setting enabled can only pull from another branch if the other branch’s log is a longer version of its own". What happens if I try to push to trunk with this setting enabled and my branch's log is not a longer version of trunk's? Will the push fail?

Comment: You will get something like "bzr: ERROR: Operation denied because it would change the mainline history. Set the append_revisions_only setting to False"

Basically you can't remove or re-order revisions on this branch. So if your new commits are based on an older revision than trunk you will have to merge with the trunk first or rebase your changes on the current trunk using the rewrite plugin (https://launchpad.net/bzr-rewrite).

Other solutions is to have a robot that does this for you like the patch queue manager, but I think thats a lot of setup. (https://launchpad.net/pqm/)